# Java.lang Runtime exception : Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo error in my app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm taking a course on Android development and one of the exercise is to make a simple Connect 3 game. I'm not sure where the error is as it's not a compilation error, so I can't figure out where to change the code.

Given below is the MainActivity.java code :

```
package com.anurag.connectthree;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// 0 = yellow, 1 = red  => means yellow goes first
int activePlayer = 0;

//save a memory state to know when a tile has been clicked
int[] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};

//check if game is won after min 5 moves
static int noOfMoves = 0;

//layout over the grid layout for playing again
private LinearLayout playAgainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

//the winner message on the linear  layout
private TextView winnerMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);

//initially true, set to false after game has been won
private boolean gameIsActive = true;

public void dropIn(View view){


    //tapped on view, so imageview is the view itself, then set resource to image as done on line 31 and 35
    ImageView counter =(ImageView) view;

    //Added tags to tiles in XML .getTag() returns tag and can act as index of gameState array
    int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

    //2 means tile hasn't been been clicked
    if(gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {

        gameState[tappedCounter]=activePlayer; //this will tell us which player is playing this move

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

        if (activePlayer == 0) {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            activePlayer = 1;
        } else {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            activePlayer = 0;
        }
        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(540f).setDuration(300);

    }

    noOfMoves++;

    Log.i("Move number ",Integer.toString(noOfMoves));

    if(noOfMoves>=5) checkForWin();

}

private void checkForWin() {
    int i,j;

    //winning combinations are {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}} horizontally, {{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8}} vertically and {{0,4,8}, {2,4,6}} diagonally
    for(i=1,j=3;i<=8&&j<=8;i+=3,j+=1){
        if((gameState[i-1]==gameState[i]&&gameState[i+1]==gameState[i])    //takes care of horizontal
                ||(gameState[j-3]==gameState[j]&&gameState[j]==gameState[j+3])   //takes care of vertical
            ||(gameState[0]==gameState[4]&&gameState[4]==gameState[8])       //hardcoding diagonal
                ||(gameState[2]==gameState[4]&&gameState[4]==gameState[6])){



            if(gameState[i]==0||gameState[j]==0||gameState[4]==0) {
                gameIsActive = false;
                winnerMessage.setText("Yellow has won!");
                if(playAgainLayout.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)
                    playAgainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            else if(gameState[i]==1||gameState[j]==1||gameState[4]==1) {
                gameIsActive = false;
                winnerMessage.setText("Yellow has won!");
                if(playAgainLayout.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)
                    playAgainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    }

}
public void playAgain(View view){

    //for playing again set the game to active again
    gameIsActive=true;

    //this is again set to invisible
    playAgainLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //game state reset to {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}
    for(int i =0; i<gameState.length;i++)
        gameState[i]=2;

    //again yellow will start, so set to 0
    activePlayer = 0;

    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    //for each of the 9 children of the grid, set their image src to null
    for(int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++){

        ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
    }

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i("Check if game starts :","Yes");

    }
}
```

Also given the log output:

```
04-26 20:55:03.639 20649-20649/? E/Zygote: v2
04-26 20:55:03.639 20649-20649/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 
10231
KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
04-26 20:55:03.641 20649-20649/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-26 20:55:03.642 20649-20649/? W/SELinux: SELinux 
selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 
RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0010, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
04-26 20:55:03.643 20649-20649/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: 
seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.anurag.connectthree 
04-26 20:55:03.648 20649-20649/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-26 20:55:03.967 20649-20649/com.anurag.connectthree I/InstantRun: 
starting instant run server: is main process
04-26 20:55:04.067 20649-20649/com.anurag.connectthree E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.anurag.connectthree, PID: 20649
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.anurag.connectthree/com.anurag.connectthree.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null 
object reference
at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2849)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null 
object reference
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init> 
(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init> 
(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init> 
(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init> 
(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init> 
(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
    at com.anurag.connectthree.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
04-26 20:55:04.093 20649-20649/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20649 SIG: 9
```

Also attaching the activity_main XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="369dp"
    android:layout_height="424dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.492"
    app:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"

        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="1"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="4" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:tag="8" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
    android:layout_width="309dp"
    android:layout_height="179dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="The winner is "
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:onClick="playAgain"
        android:text="Play Again"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Android Mainfest XML as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.anurag.connectthree">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two views (playAgainLayout and winnerMessage) being initialised as part of field declaration using `findViewById` API call.

When this class' constructor is called, first these fields are initialised.
This can be verified from your stack trace:

```
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
at com.anurag.connectthree.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)
```

Here `<init>` refers to the constructor call.

The `findViewById` can only work when the activity is attached to the window.

The first callback method in the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) is the `onCreate` method. Usually we call `setContentView` method from here to inflate our view. Since you want the views inflated from your layout file `activity_main.xml`, you should find them after calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

```
//layout over the grid layout for playing again
private LinearLayout playAgainLayout;

//the winner message on the linear  layout
private TextView winnerMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // layout is inflated, now we can find the views using findViewById
    playAgainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
    winnerMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);

    Log.i("Check if game starts :","Yes");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

View should be find inside method `onCreate()`, after `setContentView()`

```
   private LinearLayout playAgainLayou
   private TextView winnerMessage

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        winnerMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
        playAgainLayout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
    }
```